# Move a Rectangle from point to point in a ramp with changing angle

Tags: java, graphics, java-2d

So I have this program to test the possibility of an object to slide down in a ramp given its friction, object mass and ramp angle. However I need to animate the box if the force is positive. Just a simple animation moving the box from that point to the end of the ramp. But I can't. Please help

```
    private void drawTransform(Graphics g, double modifier) {
   // redtowhite = new GradientPaint(0,0,color.RED,100, 0,color.WHITE);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(130,350, 350, 15);
    Rectangle box = new Rectangle((int) (rect.getX()+300), 300, 50, 50);
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.rotate(-Math.toRadians(modifier), rect.getX(), rect.getY() + rect.height);

    // Transform the shape and draw it to screen
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
   // g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 350, 600);
    g2d.fill(at.createTransformedShape(rect));
    g2d.draw(at.createTransformedShape(box));

}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is move the box, this can be done by simply updating it's X position. You should be able to manipulate the rectangle's X position directly using something like "box.x++". Alternatively you could create a variable and reference that to provide the initial X co-ordinate, then updating that variable will "move" the box. One issue is this will *only* move the box along the X axis, hence you will also need some kind of constant downward force acting as gravity. This is easy to achieve, just minus the box's Y position value when it is not colliding with the ground, or your ramp.

Another approach is velocity based movement using vectors, however you mentioned that the animation should be simple. If you do want a smoother animation velocity based movement will provide this but you will need to perform a little research first.